# Map<Object, AtomicInteger> to Associative array

Tags: java, java-8, mapping, atomic, atomicinteger

I have for input `int[]` with the following content:

```
[5, 65, 22, 1, 58, 5, 69, 12, 1, 22, 22, 58, 12, 54, 89]
```

Using `Map<Object, AtomicInteger>`, I'm converting it to the following object:

```
{1=2, 65=1, 5=2, 69=1, 22=3, 58=2, 12=1}
```

In other words, I'm calculating the repeating elements of the dynamic array.

Now I need to find out the max and min occurrence and I'm really stuck on further steps.

The code of repeating elements class is below:

```
public Map<Object, AtomicInteger> countRepeatingElements(int[] inputArray) {
    ConcurrentMap<Object, AtomicInteger> output = 
                  new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, AtomicInteger>();

    for (Object i : inputArray) {
        output.putIfAbsent(i, new AtomicInteger(0));
        output.get(i).incrementAndGet();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Two side comments: 1. I'm curious why `Map<Object, AtomicInteger>` instead of `Map<Integer, AtomicInteger>` 2. unless this method's results are being used concurrently, you would still be fine with a `HashMap<Object, Integer>` (you can use `output.compute` to add/increment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the max and the min occurrence, iterate through the Map using the EntrySet and compare the values of each key.

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(Map.Entry<Object, AtomicInteger> entry : output.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue().intValue() < min){
        min = entry.getValue().intValue();
    }
    if(entry.getValue().intValue() > max){
        max = entry.getValue().intValue();
    }
// entry.getValue() gives you number of times number occurs
// entry.getKey() gives you the number itself
}
```

Comment: min = entry.getValue(); throws warning that should be AtomicInteger type

Comment: Updated code, Should be getValue().intValue() because you're converting an AtomicInteger to int.

Alternatively, you can set the min and max variables to AtomicInteger and change your implementation accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] inputArray = {5, 65, 22, 1, 58, 5, 69, 12, 1, 22, 22, 58, 12, 54, 89};

// 1
Map<Integer, Long> grouped = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

// 2
LongSummaryStatistics stats = grouped.values()
        .stream()
        .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
        .summaryStatistics();

System.out.println(stats.getMax());
System.out.println(stats.getMin());
```